# Jquery UI Draggable крадет фокус | JS

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Использую библиотеку Jquery UI. У меня есть диалогове окно, которое я должен перетаскивать. Проблема в том, что все поля ввода там реализованы через div[contenteditable]. Итак, как я понял, при использовании на диалоговом окне draggable фокус переходит на него, из-за чего div[contenteditable] больше не работает. Как мне решить эту проблему?

**Примечание:** я не могу сделать поле ввода инпутом, потому что не я решаю, как все должно быть.

Comment: А примеры? Ванговать тут мало кто умеет.

Comment: @De.Minov, там все на компонентах, поэтому скинуть не могу, ибо это половина проекта.

Comment: Никто не просит скидывать проект или половину.. [Минимально воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было сделать запрет на перемещение внутренних компонентов. А они хранятся у меня в классе dialog-content.

```
$(dialog).draggable({
            cancel: ".dialog-content"
        });
```